# Can the different accounts of a single Metamask user be linked to each other?

Tags: metamask

So you are a user in a single instance of Metamask with an email/pwd.

If I create different addresses inside the MetaMask instance, is there a way that a third party can find out all of my Metamask wallets are linked to the same Metamask instance (my user)?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! When you say different wallets, do you mean one instance of MetaMask, but with many different addresses?

Comment: @TheRenaissance You are right, I confuse those terms all the time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with data that is publicly available on the blockchain. Addresses are not connected to eachother in any way. If someone has access to your mnemonic phrase, extended private key or extended public key, they can link the different addresses, but of course you should never give this data out.

> So you are a user in Metamask with an email/pwd.

Note that MetaMask does not have an account system with an emailaddress and password combo. The password is only used to decrypt your locally stored mnemonic phrase.